# Which RAM can I use if I have Hewlett-Packard 2AE2 motherboard?

Tags: memory, motherboard, upgrade, compaq-desktop-computer

I already have stock 4gb 1333 mhz DDR3 RAM installed. But I feel like I need 8GB, because it is always being 75 percent or more used, often more than 85.

The problem is, I can't find that exact same type to put in the second slot.

So my question is, which 4GB ram stick can I put inside?

I live in Europe, so I would like to order something from Europe or China, not USA.

EDIT: I use 64bit Windows 10 in my Compaq CQ2951EC Desktop which has the [HP 2AE2 motherboard](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03333871).

Comment: Did you look up your motherboard specs at HP.com? What exact PC model is it?

Comment: It is an HP Compaq CCQ2951EC computer.

Answer (score 1):

The magic of Google compelled me to search for "HP 2AE2" [which revealed](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03333871):

**Memory upgrade information**
Dual channel memory architecture
Two **240-pin** DDR3 UDIMM sockets
Supports **DDR3 UDIMMs

PC3-8500 (DDR3-1066)

PC3-10600 (DDR3-1333)

PC3-12800 (DDR3-1600 with Ivy Bridge processors)**
**Non-ECC memory only, unbuffered**
Supports up to 4 GB on 32-bit* systems
Supports up to 16 GB on 64-bit systems (with 8 GB UDIMMs)
*NOTE: 32-bit systems cannot address a full 4.0 GB of memory.

If you have one 4GB memory module already in the first slot, make sure to buy exactly the same type of memory for the second slot.

Comment: Thanks for help. I found out that my PC uses an Ivy Bridge processor, so I think adding one 4gb 1600 stick will be fine. One question though, does the manufacturer make a difference, so can I have Samsung and for example Kingston at the same time?

Comment: https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com is the place to talk hardware, i.e., Samsung v. Kingston. However, I always dismount the existing memory, get the part and model numbers from it, remount it, and add a duplicate, unless I am upgrading further than another module will take me (e.g., over 8GB). Before you do anything, though, check to make sure your OS is 32-bit or 64-bit; only a 64-bit OS can use > 4GB.

Comment: This may be too specific, but are options like this suitable? https://www.amazon.com/Kingston-ValueRAM-4GB-1600MHz-DDR3/dp/B00B90PX48 or this model: Kingston Value 4GB DDR3 1600 CL11 SR STD Height 30mm.  Just to know I understood you correctly.

Comment: " so can I have Samsung and for example Kingston at the same time?" Most of the time yes you can mix different manufacturer memory modules as long as the specs are the same, no guarantees though.

Comment: Also, the voltage should be the same, right?

Comment: I know I'm probably getting really annoying, but I found out that my processor (Intel Celeron G1610T) can use only 1333 mhz ram. This changes options, I was also told that RAM should have the same latency and frequency. My ram is: Samsung ddr3 4gb ram m378b5173cbo-cko. Which latency does it have? Maybe I don't know how to search correctly, but I didn't find that.

Comment: On the other hand Crucial says, that their 1600 mhz ram is guaranteed to work. https://eu.crucial.com/eur/en/compaq-cq2951ec/CT5324435

Comment: And Intel says only 1333 mhz ram is supporeted https://ark.intel.com/products/71074/Intel-Celeron-Processor-G1610T-2M-Cache-2-30-GHz-

Comment: Whom should I trust?

Comment: Since you have the Samsung M378B5173CBO already, you won't go wrong with another: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Samsung-M378B5173QH0-CK0-1600Hz-PC3-12800-Warranty/dp/B00G1H3TA4